# Post save hook and pre updateMany hook in cyclic dependent schemas problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a ProductsGroup model that groups products in a variants array. After updating the ProductsGroup, I update the productGroup property in the product (which works well). Then, I try to remove the updated products from the previous ProductsGroup.variants array, but this part isn't working. After the update, I have products in two ProductsGroups, not just in the updated one.

Here are my schemas

**Product.js**

```
const { Schema } = mongoose

const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    url: String,
    filename: String
});

ImageSchema.virtual('thubnail').get(function () {
    return this.url.replace('/upload', '/upload/w_200')
})

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    images: [ImageSchema],
    description: String,
    metaDescription: String,
    priceN: Number,
    priceB: Number,
    SKU: String,
    variant: String,
    allegroUrl: String,
    isRecommended: Boolean,
    isOnSale: Boolean,
    isBestseller: Boolean,
    isNewProduct: Boolean,
    productGroup: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductsGroup' }
})

ProductSchema.pre(
    'updateMany', async (doc) => {
        if (doc) {
            const ProductsGroup = require('./productsGroup')
            const pg = await ProductsGroup.updateMany(
                {
                    variants: doc._id
                },
                {
                    $pullAll: {
                        variants: doc._id
                    }
                })
        }

    }

)


module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

**ProductsGroup.js**

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const Product = require('./product')

const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    url: String,
    filename: String
});

ImageSchema.virtual('thubnail').get(function () {
    return this.url.replace('/upload', '/upload/w_200')
})


const ProductsGroupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    image: ImageSchema,
    variants: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'Product' }]
})

ProductsGroupSchema.post(
    'save', async (doc, next) => {
        if (doc) {
            await Product.updateMany (
                {
                    _id: {
                        $in: doc.variants
                    }
                },
                {
                    $set: { productGroup: doc._id }
                })
        }
        next()

    }

    // ! remove variant id after includes to new pg
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('ProductsGroup', ProductsGroupSchema);
```